# Python Subprocess Failure After A Certain Quantity of Data

Tags: python, multithreading, pipe, subprocess

I am using Python and Java together for some scientific computing. Python sends permutations to the Java code to be processed. I use the subprocess object with piped data in and out. This system works great up until about 75k permuations. At that point it crashes. The strangest thing is how consistently it occurs at around 75k permuations regardless of changing other variables.

The Python code sends 50 permuations at a time, but changing this number doesn't affect when it crashes.

Having the python code run the relevant function on smaller parts of the data (40k, then 40k, etc.) doesn't affect when it crashes.

Reducing the number of simulataneous threads from 4 to 1 doesn't affect when it crashes.

Yet, it doesn't crash at a specific permutation, just around 75k (could be at 70k, could be 81k, etc.)

I'm completely mystified. 
Here's the error thrown:

```
[1:84150]  //Thread 1, permutation #84150 
Number of threads active 2
("Failure","Failure")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\TMD Projects\BE9\BE9_RestrictHB_2A_Fine\TMD_7.28.16.py", line 836, in run
returnedDataTuple = p.communicate(sentData.encode())
File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 959, in communicate
stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1190, in _communicate
self.stderr_thread.start()
File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 851, in start
_start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't start new thread
```

Here's  the relevant code, nothing too complex:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["java","-jar","WatGenDabBatchNoTP.jar","L","6","0",str(BATCH_SIZE)], stdin=subprocess.PIPE , stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
returnedData = "Failure"
returnedError = "Failure"
returnedTuple = ("Failure","Failure")
try:
   returnedTuple = p.communicate(sentData.encode())
   returnedData = returnedTuple[0].decode('utf-8')
   returnedError = returnedTuple[1].decode('utf-8')
except:
   PRINT("["+str(me.thread)+":"+str(number)+"]")
   PRINT("Number of threads active "+str(threading.activeCount()))
   PRINT(str(backTuple))
   PRINT(traceback.format_exc())
finally:
   #p.stdout.flush() //Flushing buffers throws an error
   #p.stdin.flush()
   #p.stderr.flush()
   p.terminate() //Terminating process doesn't help
   p.kill()
```

The above code is part of a loop. It sends BATCH_SIZE permutations in each run of the loop and crashes when it gets to 75-85k. 
It's run on Windows 7 and Python 3.4.2

Comment: Are you using any kind of threading to generate the permutations? See my updated answer.

Comment: Can you check if all these subprocesses are still hanging around ... Instead of being killed/ended? This would give a hint as the number of process ids - is usually constrained around 64k ... Looking at the question from a unix perspective

Comment: Dilettant - how can I check to see if these threads are hanging around other than the number of active threads. When I set to only have one instance of java running the program consistently has only 2 active threads as per threading.activeCount() but still crashes.

Answer (score 2):

Some things to try:

1. Change BATCH_SIZE to something very small. Does the program still crash? Does the program crash after the same number of iterations through the loop as before, or does it crash after the same number of records have been processed?

I suspect you are leaking a thread on every iteration. If that is the case, the program should run out of threads after the same number of iterations through the loop even if BATCH_SIZE is a small number.

On the other hand, the problem may be related to the total number of records processed by the loop. Varying BATCH_SIZE will help to determine
if this is the case.

2. Try adding `p.wait()` in the `finally` block. I would first try `p.wait()` alone (without calling `p.kill()` or `p.terminate()`).
3. Instead of calling your Java program, have it call a simple program which just prints out some dummy data. If the problem persists it would
   eliminate the Java program as being part of the problem.
4. Simplify the program as much as possible. Use only one processing thread. Remove the use of threading / subprocess from any other part of your program. Instead of generating the permutations, pre-calculate each batch and save it in a file. Then use
   a simple for-loop to feed them to your Java program. This will help
   determine if the way you are calling `subprocess.Popen` is the culprit
   or not.

Comment: 1: I've already played with batch size. It's consistently the number of records (although approximately, never the same record). The number of iterations through the loop doesn't matter, nor the number of threads. Always about 75k records. 

2: I tried this just now. The failure still occurs but now doesn't spill over into other threads. The other threads crash soon but not immediately after. I'm going to try with one thread next.

Will try 3 and 4 now.

Comment: 3: The dummy program does not cause this error even after all 150k poses.

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with the data returned by the Java program. Or perhaps what you are doing with the data afterwards.

Comment: The results for #4 just crashed at 86k. I totally removed all multithreading within the python code itself.  The batch has always been pre-calculated, even before this trouble. I checked the non-multithreaded version on a smaller dataset and it worked fine. Nevertheless, on this large dataset after 86k records I got the same error:
"Can't start new thread"
The java isn't throwing any errors, and I'm 100% sure it's not an error in the post-processing. The java could be messing with the pipeline or pipe buffer in some way but I don't know how to diagnose that.